# Display an image to the left of two spans

Tags: html, css

so i managed to display two spans under each other in a table row.
I did this by putting float:left and clear:left on the span element, so that is fine. Only now the two spans are displayed to the left of the image and i cannot seem to find a solution for it.

How do i get the image to display to the left? I try to avoid using position:absolute (:

I tried the internet, but i can't find my solution there.
I tried Z-index, position, inline-block, flex.

For the code it's just a table row with a image and two spans in it.
The spans got clear:left and float:left so they stack above each other.

Image of what the problem is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz7HK.png)

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Add your HTML & CSS Code Here & also add what you want

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Does this necessarily have to be in a table? This can be set up using div's - a container on the left that holds the image, and another container to the right to hold the spans on top of one another. Check out this fiddle (forgive the big mess of gibberish for the image - it was the quickest way for me to get a test image in there. Here is the link --- https://jsfiddle.net/9w7o80hf/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
.page{
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 300px;
      min-height: 155px;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <p>Campaign Name</p>
            <hr>
            <div style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%">
                <div style="width: 50%">
                    <img src="https://static.acer.com/up/Resource/Acer/Laptops/Swift_5/Photogallery/20181105/Acer-Swift-5-SF515-51T-Blue-photogallery-02.png" alt="acer" style="height: 100px;">
                </div>
                <div style="width: 50%">
                    <h3>Acer Swift 5</h3>
                    <span style="background-color: #00ab70; color: white; padding: 4px; border-radius: 3px;">FR</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```